# Is it possible using css to access anchor tag's text?

Tags: html, css

Following is my HTML

```
<a href="/content/testsite/en_gb/home/acis.html" class="">Branding</a>
```

Is it possible to access using CSS to access anchor tag's text?
Something like this is what I want? The html is dynamically generated, so please don't mention to have id's or to have any classes.

```
a[text='Branding']
{
}
```

Comment: Asked and answered. Unfortunately the answer is no. [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: With CSS you can target an element, an attribute or an attribute's value. You can't target an element's content with CSS, except for particular cases involving input fields and the value attribute. So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Michael_B that's a great answer :)

Comment: Ya i agree @Michael_B that's a great answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People already told you that you CAN'T select *text* in CSS. But there's some workaround in my opinion.
I don't know what you want to do, possibly a bad thing, but if I were you I'd take this **bad practice**:

```
/*First you hide the text*/
a {
   font-size: 0; /* hide text */
   text-decoration: none !important; /* get rid of that awful underline */
}
/* then you insert a new element using :before */
a:before {
    content: 'Branding'; /* This is the text you want for the new element */
    color: #333;
    font-size: 15px; /* Bring back the text inside the anchor for this new element */
    font: 24px sans-serif;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsu7z546/

### In case you want to try out jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var brandingAnchor = $('a:contains("Branding")');

    brandingAnchor.hide();
});
```

**Remember!** Every time you write jQuery code, you must have already called jQuery library on your page, just like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Your jQuery code goes HERE, just below the library

$(document).ready(function(){

    var brandingAnchor = $('a:contains("Branding")');

    brandingAnchor.hide();
});

</script>
```

Comment: My scenario is like I  have 5 anchor tags dynamically generated like with different text, I need to hide the one that comes with text Branding

Comment: Are you able to use javascript on that page? If not, then I'm afraid you're doomed.

Comment: If I have an unique url then I could access like a[href=''] correct? Then possibly I could try out that way

Comment: Exactly, if you know the url, you can use it to select that specific anchor, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/1g5537nb/

Comment: Is there a jquery solution to check if the anchor text is branding then hide for some reasons the css doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes... You want to target only "Branding" or EVERY anchor text with the word "branding"? I'll update my post with the code

Comment: Please, check the code.. I updated it just after my comment.